# MS SQL server data truncation on table creation

Tags: sql-server

'Test_Table' table
Unable to create table.
String or binary data would be truncated when trying to create a table through the design view

When trying to create the table with ddl, I get an error
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Procedure Log_Table_DDL, Line 30
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

I understand that this message usually comes up from an insert in which the column size is smaller than the data that is being inserted.  It seems like this is trying to insert something into one of the logs but I cannot find where.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Speaking_Details]
( 
    EventID [char](12) NULL
    , iTitle [nvarchar](MAX) NULL
    , [iHeader] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL
    , [iBody] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL
    , [iFooter] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL
    , [deadline] [smalldatetime] NULL
    , [active] [bit] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: show your create table statement

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Speaking_Details](
 EventID [char](12) NULL,
 iTitle [nvarchar](MAX) NULL,
 [iHeader] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL,
 [iBody] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL,
 [iFooter] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL,
 [deadline] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 [active] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: I am able to create table, so now issue with your database size, memory allocation size, page size...

Comment: I figured as I am able to create the same table on a different database.

Comment: It looks like there's a DDL trigger in your database - `Log_Table_DDL`. Whatever this trigger is doing (on line 30) is causing the truncation message.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the ddl. However, I would argue that you don't really have a table here. Every column is nullable and you have no primary key. Also, do you really need nvarchar(max) for everything. Surely most of those columns could be 8,000 characters or fewer.

Comment: Can you please show us the lines from 20-40 from the DDL trigger with the description of the variables in use in those lines?

Comment: @ed Harper - How did you know that it was a trigger.  Can you answer that so I can up vote?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says (emphasis mine):

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Procedure **Log_Table_DDL**, Line 30

This indicates that the issue is being caused by line 30 of an object called `Log_Table_DDL`. The only way I can think of that creating a table could cause a procedure error like this is if `Log_Table_DDL` is a [DDL trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx).

You'll need to post the definition of the DDL trigger for more specific help about the cause of the issue.